# non-const lvalue reference to type 'pair<...>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'pair<...>'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a reference to the emplaced item using `auto&` syntax, but it fails to compile with above error.

How can I get reference to emplaced item in this case?

I've attempted to use `const auto&` but the object seems invoking destructor on my actual app so thus it seems to be a fake reference at best.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class Connection {
   public:
     bool foo{};
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Connection> connections;

    auto& [connection, inserted] = connections.try_emplace("test");
}
```

Comment: Can not reproduce: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ThWzh45f5. You need to show minimal example as per your code.

Comment: If this is your exact code and gives the error in the title, then it might be a compiler bug,  what version and build of compiler?

Comment: note that `connection` is an iterator not the inserted object

Comment: `non-const lvalue reference` in the error message suggests that your code is actually `auto& [connection, inserted]` not `const auto& [connection, inserted]`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, my code is auto& not const auto& but I tried with const auto& and it gives me fake reference

Comment: @Const My code is auto& not const auto& but I tried with const auto& and it gives me fake reference

Comment: You should post the exact code which causes the error you are asking about . Not some different code with a different error.

Comment: @M.M Sorry, I was working for hours straightly and it was an accident. I posted the const auto& by accident..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `try_emplace` returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`, which is a temporary, NOT a reference to the inserted element. See [description on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace)

After emplacing, you could say

```
auto& elem = connections["test"];
```

or

```
auto [connection, inserted] = connections.try_emplace("test");
auto& elem = *connection;
```

for example, to get a reference to the element.

The first variant returns a reference to the actual value associated with the key `test`, whereas the second one returns a reference to the map element, which is a `pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`, i.e. the first version essentially returns `second` of said pair directly.

`const auto&` compiles because it is legal to declare a `const` reference to a temporary, but not a non-`const` lvalue reference.

Comment: Does your latter example gives a reference to inserted element or the temporary (fake) element?

Comment: there is no temporary element, the element is inserted (or not if the insertion fails) into the map and the iterator and the reference returned by dereferencing the iterator points to that element

Comment: @jeffbRTC To the inserted element. In the second example, I dereference the iterator, which returns a reference to the actual element.

Comment: But what exactly are we dereferencing here? Does the iterator returns a pointer to element?

Comment: @AlanBirtles The reason I used temporary element on my comments is because const auto& was not working and it seems pointed to a temporary element

Comment: The `const auto&` version should still work (binding const reference to a prvalue extends the lifetime, this still applies to structured bindings). I agree it would be better style to use `auto` instead of `const auto&` but they should both work if you're not going to modify the object

Comment: @M.M I of course need to modify the object. The modification succeeded with const auto& but I saw that on my actual app the life time is not extended.

Comment: @jeffbRTC the lifetime is extended (you must be misinterpreting whatever you are seeing). It might be a good idea to post a new question with a Minimal Reproducible Example showing the unexpected behaviour of `const auto&` .   (don't edit this question since these are two different issues)

Comment: Container iterators refer to a `value_type` of the container, which in this case is `pair<const Key, T>`. It could be a raw pointer, or a class type overloading `operator*`, that detail is transparent to the caller. When you dereference the iterator it gives you an lvalue expression of type `pair<const Key, T>`.  that refers into the map directly (not to a temporary copy of the entry)

Comment: @M.M Understood